# New SQL Server Wait Type - BPSORT

Tags: sql-server, wait, sql-server-2016

I've encountered this new wait type while messing around with some ETL.  A quick search didn't turn up anything online.

Anyone know what this is?

Comment: some search indicates, you might having column store index and this wait is related to sorting the batch

Comment: not 100% sure tough,voting to migrate this question to DBA.SE,as you might get good response

Comment: [Batch processing mode for sort](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4587/sql-server-2016-sort-order-batch-processing-mode/). The question is why this is a wait, and what exactly the wait is for -- supplying rows? One step of batch sorting?

Comment: It's a clustered columnstore :)

Answer (score 1):

> TThis wait type is when a thread is involved in a batch-mode sort (only around columnstore indexes prior to SQL Server 2019).

[source](https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/bpsort/)

It can be disabled by enabling [Trace Flag 9347](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-traceon-trace-flags-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).